# when we combine two text columns in python why does the words get scrambled up while creating tf-idf vectorizer

Tags: python

When we combine two text columns in python, why does the words get scrambled up while creating *tf-idf vectorizer*.

```
`concatenated_data['combine'] = concatenated_data.Product_Name.astype(str).str.cat(concatenated_data.Reviews.astype(str), sep='\t'`)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Can you show an example here. It would be helpful.

Comment: basically i have two text columns (product names) and (reviews) and i want to combine these two columns like i have done in the above lie but the problem i am facing is when i try to create a tfidf vector of words from this combined column the worfs don't get scrambled up while creating features so on the bottom line i want the words in the combine column to get scrambled up while creating freatures